# sql How to choose results using HAVING correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I have the following 2 tables (showing only sum of the columns here):

```
CUSTOMER:id, fname, lname.
SALES_ORDER: id, cust_id, sales_rep.
```

And the id from CUSTOMER connects with the cust_id from SALES_ORDER.
What I need to do is: Return customer details + number of orders made by that customer, for customers that have had at least one order handled by employee number '129'. This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT customer.id, fname, lname, count(*) 
FROM customer,
     sales_order
WHERE customer.id = sales_order.cust_id
GROUP BY customer.id
HAVING sales_rep = 129;
```

This does indeed return customers that answer the above + the number of order they had...but upon browsing the DB I see there are other clients that weren't fetched by the query. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: mysql or (ms)sql-server?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions. Use WHERE for regular conditions.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you but I still don't understand why my query doesn't work. It didn't give me an error on using HAVING with a regular condition, but it also gave me only some of the results.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT customer.id, fname, lname, count(*) 
FROM customer,
     sales_order
WHERE customer.id = sales_order.cust_id
GROUP BY customer.id
HAVING MAX(IIF(sales_rep = 129, 1, 0)) = 1;
```

The idea is to calculated the count, but show only these records, where at least on of the `sales_rep` is `129`. We are using `IIF` (you can use `CASE WHEN` for older SQL Server versions) to check if a particular record is for the specific `sales_rep` and `MAX` to check for at least one such record.

---

If you do not want to use `HAVING` you can filter the rows using additional filtering criteria:

```
SELECT customer.id, fname, lname, count(*) 
FROM customer
INNER JOIN sales_order
    ON customer.id = sales_order.cust_id
WHERE customer.id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customer.id
    FROM sales_order
    WHERE sales_rep = 129
)
GROUP BY customer.id
```

The idea is to calculated the count for each customer and then using a `WHERE` clause to display only users you have at least one `sales_rep = 129`.

Comment: This might work but it uses IIF which I don't know and not supposed to use at this point. What I was wondering is if someone could explain to me why my query doesn't work - it fetches some but not all

Comment: You can use `CASE sales_rep = 129 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `